# XML unexpected token

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to get a list of shows using TVRage - An example provided uses this:

```
Show show = new Show(showName);

XElement xml = XDocument.Load("http://www.tvrage.com/feeds/episode_list.php?show=" + showName).Element("Show");
```

The error is:

> "'text' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '\"' or '''

I cannot find any info

Comment: What does the xml look like? You are getting an error because it can't parse the xml. We can't help you unless we know what is making the error.

Comment: Does it return XML to you? If you copy that URL into fiddler, what do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your search returned an error, for two reasons:

- The initial part of your URL is wrong - rather than passing `www`, you must pass `services`
- The `episode_list` API does not take show name, it takes show ID.

Try this:

```
XElement xml = XDocument.Load("http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/episode_list.php?sid=" + showId).Element("Show");
```

In order to find show ID by show name, execute a search by querying this URL:

`"http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/search.php?show=" + showName`

The results would look like this:

```
<Results>
    <show>
        <showid>6190</showid> <!-- <<<<<<< Grab this number -->
        ...
    </show>
</Results>
```

Plug in `showId` that you get from the search into the URL above to get a list of episodes.

Comment: @user2471267 You are welcome! If your problem is solved, consider accepting an answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would let other site visitors know that you are no longer actively looking for an improved solution to the problem, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

According to your variable it looks like you are expecting a ShowName. If you are only given a show name then you need to retrieve a list of shows that match the name given:

```
XElement xml = XDocument.Load("http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/search.php?show=" + showName).Element("Show");
```

This will return all Shows that match the Search Criteria. It might include shows you don't want.

From there you can retrieve the ShowID of the show you want within the XML Results and use dasblinkenlight's answer to retrieve list of episodes for that particular show Id.

For API reference purposes: http://services.tvrage.com/info.php?page=main